# WHM / CPANEL and ImageMagick-devel 6 conflict with ImageMagick 7

Tags: imagemagick, cpanel, whm

I installed ImageMagick 7

I have CentOS 8 with latest WHM

but when I do yum install ImageMagick => it wants to install 6.9, but 7 is already installed.

** QUESTION 1 :** is it possible to force WHM not to want to install ImageMagick-devel ???

** QUESTION 2 :** is 1 is not possible => then can I force (other way than yum.conf) to make dnf or yum to never see any ImageMagick 6.9 ????

When I create a support ticket, they seems only refers to yum.conf everytime. but that doesn't address the issue.

I even went and tried to `"ln -s"` any ImageMagick7 to ImageMagick6 in /usr/include/ and other places that the ImageMagick Libs is installed, but that didn't do anything.

because I tried editing yum.conf and added `exclude=Image-Magick-devel` but that is still the error of not being able to install required packages......

when the update script runs this `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/sysup`

I get those errors

```
info [sysup] ea4: repo already installed
checkyum version 22.3  (excludes: bind-chroot kernel ruby)
checkyum version 22.3  (excludes: bind-chroot kernel)
info [sysup] Starting yum execution “--assumeyes --color=never --config /etc/yum.conf install ImageMagick-devel --enablerepo=powertools --enablerepo=epel”.
Last metadata expiration check: 2:19:16 ago on Fri Jul  9 14:54:34 2021.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                Arch        Version                     Repo       Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 ImageMagick-devel      x86_64      1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi      remi      136 k
Installing dependencies:
 ImageMagick            x86_64      1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi      remi      103 k
 ImageMagick-libs       x86_64      1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi      remi      2.4 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  3 Packages

Total size: 2.7 M
Installed size: 8.8 M
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] ImageMagick-6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] ImageMagick-devel-6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
[SKIPPED] ImageMagick-libs-6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded 
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/bin/animate from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/compare from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/composite from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/conjure from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/convert from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/display from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/identify from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/import from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mogrify from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/montage from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/stream from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/ImageMagick.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/animate.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/compare.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/composite.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/conjure.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/convert.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/display.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/identify.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/import.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mogrify.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/montage.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/stream.1.gz from install of ImageMagick-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/MagickCore-config from install of ImageMagick-devel-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-devel-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/MagickWand-config from install of ImageMagick-devel-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-devel-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc from install of ImageMagick-devel-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-devel-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc from install of ImageMagick-devel-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-devel-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/MagickWand.pc from install of ImageMagick-devel-1:6.9.11.60-1.el8.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package ImageMagick7-devel-7.1.0.2-1.el8.remi.x86_64

info [sysup] Completed yum execution “--assumeyes --color=never --config /etc/yum.conf install ImageMagick-devel --enablerepo=powertools --enablerepo=epel”: in 4.886 second(s).
(XID 7t4cua) “/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/retry_rpm” reported error code “1” when it ended: 
checkyum version 22.3  (excludes: bind-chroot ruby)
E Sysup: Needed system RPMs were not installed: ImageMagick-devel
```

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is your real goal

Packages in my repository are designed to allow parallel installation of various library versions

- ImageMagick-libs, from EPEL, old version 6.9.10 (used by some app from EPEL)
- ImageMagick6-libs for latest version 6.9.12 (used by php-pecl-imagick-im6 or vips-magick-im6)
- ImageMagick6-libs for latest version 7.1.0 (used by php-pecl-imagick-im6 or vips-magick-im7)

But you can only install 1 version of the commands (ImageMagick) and of the development headers (ImageMagick-devel)

So looks like cpanel is not able to manage such configuration.

Comment: Cpanel level 3 was finally able to answer this, see my answer

Comment: My goal was to stop `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/sysup` to scream at me about ImageMagick-devel .... now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

A Cpanel level III was able to pinpoint the issue, fix it and PLUS : do a post explaining everything ;)

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4403997242775-CentOS-8-Sysup-failure-if-ImageMagick7-installed-from-the-REMI-repository?source=search&auth_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjo5Mjc3OTc5LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjozODkxMzkxNTk2NTQsInRpY2tldF9pZCI6OTQzNDI2OTksImNoYW5uZWxfaWQiOjYzLCJ0eXBlIjoiU0VBUkNIIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI4NDc4MTc0fQ.iAVLyknZaWernw8T1op8D7pxOLSFrz6WcuPBeYy0qh0

Workaround

```
Ignore the errors or Modify the cPanel update requirement manually to suppress the errors.

sed -i.bak '/ImageMagick-devel/d' /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Sysup.pm
echo /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Sysup.pm >> /etc/cpanelsync.exclude
/scripts/upcp
```

To return the cPanel update system to normal functionality, remove the updates exclude file.

```
/bin/rm /etc/cpanelsync.exclude
```